# jQuery ":selected" filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

When trying to get the value of selected option on a dynamically added select when clicking a button I get always undefined.

```
$(document).on('click', '#ChangeResp', (function(){
var test = $(document).find('#responsiblelist');
var test2 = $(test).filter(":selected").val();
console.log(test2);
}));
```

If I do `console.log(test)` I see the correct element is being picked.

**EDIT#1** I'm using select2

Here is the HTML code.

```
<div class="form-group is-empty">
    <label class="control-label" for="responsiblelist"><strong>Responsible Name</strong></label></br >
    <select id="responsiblelist" title="Select Responsible" class="select2_single form-control" tabindex="-1">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1"></option>
        <option value="2"></option>
        <option value="3"></option>
    </select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on('click', '#ChangeResp', (function(){
    var username = $(document).find('#responsiblelist').children("option").filter(":selected").val();
    console.log(username);
}));

</script>
```

The reason why I'm getting always undefined is because I'm always getting first option which has no value (this is a requirement for select2 usage) otherwise I would start select with one option already selected.

Comment: `#responsiblelist` is presumably the `<select>`, but `:selected` applies to the `<option>`s.

Comment: Why don't you just use `test.val()`?

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your whole code

Comment: Doesn't work. Gives me undefined. The value attribue is set on the `<option>` I've tried getting the value with multiple ways even through attr "value" and nothing.

Comment: Please post some HTML

Comment: Done, please look at answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('select[name=responsiblelist]').val()
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `#responsiblelist` was added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Look through the children of the list, then use `filter` to get the value of your selected `option`

```
$(document).on('click', '#ChangeResp', (function(){      
    var test = $("#responsiblelist").children("option").filter(":selected").val​();
    console.log(test);
}));
```

Comment: you don't even need to select the selected option do you?

Comment: Keep in mind that `#responsiblelist` was added dynamically.

Comment: @rgomez that shouldn't matter

Comment: I must I've tried your first answer. Thank you it worked.

Comment: I've just found that it's always returning the value of first option, never de selected one. I'm using select2 on my page.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the value of the selected option, it can be much simpler:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ChangeResp', (function(){
  var test = $('#responsiblelist').val();
  console.log(test);
}));
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't know `#responsiblelist`because it wasn't there when jQuery was loaded

Comment: That is irrelevant, it just has to be present at the time of the click.